# Install older version of Yaml (1.3.1) for PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, ubuntu, yaml, pecl

I tried to install yaml by using this commands

```
 sudo apt-get install php-pear libyaml-dev
 sudo pecl install yaml
```

But this YAML requires php7.0 and newer version. I use PHP 5.5.9
How can install older version of YAML.

Comment: Why not try a composer installable YAML component like `symfony/yaml`? You don't need to use Symfony framework in order to start using it! https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html

Comment: I need to create yaml file dinamicly, I am installed this component.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778

Comment: Stevan, check this section, the composer lib can also write as well as read and parse. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#writing-yaml-files

Comment: You're probably well aware of this already, but please note that PHP 5.5 is obsolete and no longer supported by the PHP developers. The lowest supported version currently is 5.6, but don't count on even that being supported for too much longer. You should be planning seriously right now for how you're going to upgrade your systems to PHP 7, because if you don't, you're going to get yourself into a position where you've got a major security flaw and you're stuck on a version that isn't getting patched.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks, delboy, I had found a solution with your suggestion.

Comment: @Simba Yes I am aware, but there is a lot of clients that use an older version of PHP on their servers and before they decide to upgrade their projects we are forced to play game on their rule. Btw you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your package repository (For example in Debian/Ubuntu Aptitude repositories), for PHP5 versions and then install that version or YAML.

You can use also Composer for the dependencies management, or the "hardest" way, download the source code and implement by yourself.

```
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list


wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- |apt-key add -

apt-get update
apt-get install php-pearl ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As  delboy1978uk suggested I had tried with Symfony

> Stevan, check this section, the composer lib can also write as well as
>   read and parse.
>   symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#writing-yaml-fi‌​les –
>   delboy1978uk

This is my working solution

```
$arr = array(
               'parameters' => array(
                    'stage' => array(
                    'host' => 'host',
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' =>  'password'
                ),
                   'live'=> array(
                       'host' => 'host',
                       'username' => 'username',
                       'password' =>  'password'
                   ),
           )
       );

        $yaml = Yaml::dump($arr, 3);

        file_put_contents('parameters.yml', $yaml);
```

This code outputs

```
parameters:
    stage:
        host: sasass
        username: dsdadsd
        password: password
    live:
        host: sasass
        username: dsdadsd
        password: password
```

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help! Looks nice and easy to use too!